# How can I delete an item from the cart in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

How can I delete an item from the cart in without going to the cart page? Can I create a form which deletes a single item from cart when submitted?

Comment: Do you need something dynamic or a Liquid form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.get("/cart/change?line=1&quantity=0");
```

worked for me but it does not update counter next to the cart icon.